# Country Flag Tags - See mini-country flags next to tags on Money.SE

Tags: script

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Screenshot of the script in action.]

### About

This UserScript was inspired by [this post on Meta.Money.SE](https://money.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/425/can-we-add-pictures-of-country-flags-to-country-tags). One of the users requested that tiny country flags be added to tags where appropriate. Another user made the comment that this could easily be done with CSS - which inspired me to create this UserScript that does exactly that (well, okay - it uses some JavaScript too).

#### License

[The MIT License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php)

#### Download

You can download the script here:
http://files.quickmediasolutions.com/userscripts/flag_tags.user.js

#### Platform

This script should run on any browser that supports UserScripts.

### Contact

I can be reached at `admin@quickmediasolutions.com`.

### Code

Written in JavaScript using jQuery.

Comment: This could be useful on travel.SE, too.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Great idea!

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann: Okay, done! A lot of countries / states are missing because I used the tags from Money.SE, but the script will now work on Travel.SE. I'll consider adding more flags soon.